# Maven class name collision in Stanford-CoreNLP and Stanford-Parser

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, stanford-nlp

My (maven)project is dependent on both stanford-CoreNLP and stanford-Parser and apparently the (lexicalized)parser of each dependency is producing different outputs, they are not alike.

My question is that how can I determine which package the parser should be loaded from ? the parser class has a same name in both packages:
    `edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser`
and maven automatically loads the class from stanford-coreNLP package while I want it to be loaded from stanford-Parser.

I'd appreciate if you please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: Do they have the same package name and the same class name ?

Comment: Yes, the package and class name is same but the maven artifact ID is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would raise a bug asking them to move the lexical parser into a new maven artifact (or several of them), so you can distinguish them.

If that doesn't happen, you have two options:

1. Use the Maven shade plugin (as suggested by ooxi)
2. Delete the offending classes

Breakdown of the second approach:

1. Use you favorite ZIP tool to open the JAR archive.
2. Delete the offending packages.
3. Copy the original POM
4. Change the version version to something like `1.1.MythBuster.1` or `1.1.no-lexer.1`
5. Use `mvn file:install` to install the modified artifact in your local repo
6. Test it
7. Use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to install the modified artifact in your company's repo

I prefer the second approach since it makes sure the build has a clean classpath, people know that you messed with the original file and it's pretty obvious what is going on.

Comment: +1 especially for filing a bug, but also for the technical solutions

Answer (score 2):

I once had this problem and could solve it by using a virtual package depending on the two conflicting dependencies (in your case stanford-CoreNPL and stanford-Parser) and merging them using the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

When shading only one class will be in the virtual package, depending on the order of `<dependency />` tags.